# How to interact with Web UI inside browser

Tags: android, android-uiautomator, uitest

My app opens browser, and test needs to fill input fields and press the button at webpage to proceed. Is there any test framework/library for UIAutomator, that will give me possibility to interact with webpage UI.

Comment: @Tigger there is a library for Espresso to interact with WebView, but Espresso won't work in my case. Adding execution of JS will work, but can I obtain a WebView from browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CulebraTester](http://culebra.dtmilano.com/) can interact with browser content and is intended to test multiple apps.

You can see a screenshot of the View tree also including the web content: [Feature:hover-hierarchy webcontent](https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester-public/wiki/Features#hover-hierarchy)

[image]